# Why is the Angular server trying to access nonexistent vendor source map files?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm spinning up my Angular CLI server like this:

```
ng serve --proxy http://localhost:3000
```

(I want to proxy all ajax requests to `localhost:3000` because I have a Rails server running there.)

When I load the page, it works, but my log output looks like this:

```
GET /vendor/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js.map 404 507.868 ms - -
GET /vendor/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js.map 404 209.116 ms - -
GET /vendor/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform_browser_dynamic.js.map 404 341.069 ms - -
GET /vendor/@angular/compiler/index.js.map 404 436.576 ms - -
GET /vendor/@angular/compiler/compiler.js.map 404 563.992 ms - -
GET /vendor/@angular/compiler/src/schema/element_schema_registry.js.map 404 654.152 ms - -
GET /vendor/@angular/compiler/src/compiler.js.map 404 747.154 ms - -
GET /vendor/@angular/core/index.js.map 404 633.265 ms - -
GET /vendor/@angular/core/src/metadata.js.map 404 589.541 ms - -
GET /vendor/@angular/core/src/metadata/di.js.map 404 578.612 ms - -
GET /api/cars.json 304 460.917 ms - -
GET /vendor/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.js.map 404 465.870 ms - -
GET /vendor/@angular/core/src/di/metadata.js.map 404 454.124 ms - -
GET /vendor/@angular/core/src/di/forward_ref.js.map 404 455.020 ms - -
```

This one request is legit:

```
GET /api/cars.json 304 460.917 ms - -
```

That's my ajax request to load the data my app needs. But all the other requests are somewhat mysterious. When I run `ng serve` with no proxy flag, I don't get any of the vendor source map file requests.

Angular CLI is serving everything out of `/dist`. I do have, e.g. a `/dist/vendor/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js` file present, just no `/dist/vendor/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js.map`. I don't have *any* vendor map files, although my vendor files do have source map annotations at the bottom, e.g. `//# sourceMappingURL=Reflect.js.map`.

Seems like either the source map files should be present or they shouldn't be referenced. Why is the server trying to get these nonexistent source map files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a response on [this issue I opened](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/706), "These were left out intentionally (by me) because they slowed down the dev rebuilds."

I was able to fix the problem by changing my `angular-cli-build.js` to this:

```
/* global require, module */

var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/*.{js,js.map}',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/*.{js,js.map}',
      'rxjs/**/*.{js,js.map}',
      '@angular/**/*.{js,js.map}'
    ]
  });
};
```